# add theme to custom menu page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a wordpress plugin. I am new to this. Now I have created a menu page in wordpress. It shows a list of items retrieved from database. But they are just raw text in a blank page. How could I make it consistent with the rest of wordpress?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your efforts thus far?

Answer (score 0):

Include `get_header();` and `get_footer();`, like this

```
<?php

get_header();

/**
 * write your code here
 */


?>

<p> Go Padres </p>

<?php
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. Finally, I found what I need is WP_List_Table. I created a wordpress admin table using WP_List_Table.